# how can i disable checkboxes properly in jframe?

Tags: java, user-interface, checkbox, jframe, jpanel

Im trying to create a gui, it has some checkbox and another components, under the start test buton there are some tests. when i click this button, firstly,disable all checkbox, after that start all checked tests. And then enable all failed test's checkbox.

[image]

problem is that; i clicked start button, all checkbox turn disable but in code side (i show it with breakpoint)!! did not disable in gui. **All tests finished**, and all fail tests turn enable other success tests turn disable successfully.
here is my codes template

```
btnStartTests.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            disable_all_checkbox();
            startSelectedTests();
            bla_bla_bla();
        }
    }
```

how can i disable these checkboxes properly (in click start button time)?

Comment: @JBNizet you are right, i updated my post. there is a code template. i am thinking your suggest but is there any easy way update this cause immediately? thanks..

Comment: Well, run the tests in a background thread. For exampe using a SwingWorker. It's not that hard, and there's no way around it.

Comment: thanks your suggest  @JBNizet

Comment: @JBNizet God Bless you :) your suggest is clearly run for me. thank you so much..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use SwingWorker class, it is clearly runnig as i want thanks to @JBNizet

```
 SwingWorker<Void,Void> worker2 = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>(){
     @Override
     protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
              disable_all_checkbox();
              startSelectedTests();
              bla_bla_bla();
              return null;
     }
 };
```